# Align textviews to left and right

Tags: android

I have problem with textviews alignment. I want to align two textviews for the listview item to left and to right. In the Android Studio editor it's ok but when I'm deploying application to the device it's not right aligned. I don't know what is the problem. Below is my layout:

Found the problem. Issue actually was with the listview by mistake I set Listview's layout_width="wrap_content" but should be match_parent. As the mentioned layout is the list's item layout. Thanks everyone.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_order_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_order_category_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_order_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="35sp"/>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/order_tin_ein"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_order_tin_ein"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Test"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/order_address"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_order_address"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/order_email"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_order_email"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/order_phone"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_order_phone"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/order_mobile"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_order_mobile"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/order_fax"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_order_fax"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/order_created_date"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_order_created_date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/order_start_working_date"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_order_start_working_date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/order_end_date"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_order_end_date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/order_cost"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_order_cost"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/order_vat"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_order_vat"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: your code is ok. when we deploy in my device.

Comment: It's strange on my device it's not ok with android 6.0

Comment: where show your text in device

Comment: near the first textview

Comment: Do you use them in fragment?

Comment: No. It's not in fragment

Answer (score 1):

I think your code it's fine, and this one will improve for your code better. 
Just using gravity:right if you wanna put it on the right.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="asd"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_order_tin_ein"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Test" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried it but the second textview is not aligned to the right it's ok on the right side but it's near first textview.

Comment: And also there more textview which I would like to align like I mentioned.

Comment: Can you show me the layout exactly you want? And when the layout_width of your TextView is match_parent, you must use gravity instead of layout_gravity

Comment: For me your code is fine but for you I don't know why it haven't worked. So I suggest another way to make it, you can use the RelativeLayout to do this one

Comment: <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="asd"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="123"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

Comment: Strange thing actually cos in the IDE it's showing normal.

Comment: Try to clean project and rebuild it

Comment: Didn't help. Same thing.

Comment: I have some rendering problem. Can it cause the issue?

Comment: The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text1"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="Text2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```